# How to define a static function inherited from a virtual one?

Tags: c++, inheritance, static, virtual-functions

I am using C++ for a little application.
I have one parent class that has a virtual method. Here it's the header file.

```
class personDB:public person
{
public:
    unsigned int id;
public:
    personDB();
    personDB(QString dbName, QString dbSurname);
    personDB(QString dbName, QString dbSurname, unsigned int dbid);
    personDB(std::string dbName, std::string dbSurname, unsigned int dbid);
    virtual std::string getTableName();
    unsigned int getID(void);
    void setID(unsigned int myID);
private:
    static const std::string tableName;
};
```

This class is inherited by different child classes. Each child class redefines the `tableName` attribute assigning a different value in the *.cpp file. The attribute is private and is returned by a getter.
As an example of one of the child classes here is header file:

```
#include "persondb.h"
class ScriptBy : public personDB
{
public:
    ScriptBy();
    ScriptBy(QString dbName, QString dbSurname);
    ScriptBy(QString dbName, QString dbSurname, unsigned int dbid);
    std::string getTableName();
protected:
    static const std::string tableName;
};
```

I want to make the function getTableName() a class member function so that it returns the same value for all the instances of the same class and can be called even without an instance of the class. This should be done by putting the keyword `static` before the function declaration in the header file if I am not wrong. However when I try to compile in this way it gives me an error related to the fact that the function in the parent class was declared virtual.
The error I get is this:

```
In file included from ../../singlestory.h:4:0,
                 from ../../volume.h:5,
                 from ../../dbinterface.h:8,
                 from ../../dbinterface.cpp:1:
../../scriptby.h:12:24: error: ‘static std::__cxx11::string ScriptBy::getTableName()’ cannot be declared
     static std::string getTableName();
                        ^
In file included from ../../dbinterface.h:7:0,
                 from ../../dbinterface.cpp:1:
../../persondb.h:15:25: error:   since ‘virtual std::__cxx11::string personDB::getTableName()’ declared in base class
     virtual std::string getTableName();
```

Is there a way to make the inherited class member function static?

EDIT: If I cannot make the function static, how can I make the private attribute accessible outside without an instance of the class (and keeping it private)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution using the [Curiously Recurring template pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).

The solution that worked for me is the following:

file persondb.h

```
#ifndef PERSONDB_H
#define PERSONDB_H

#include "person.h"
#include"common.h"
class personDB:public person
{
public:
    using person::person;
    personDB(QString dbName, QString dbSurname, unsigned int dbid);
    personDB(std::string dbName, std::string dbSurname, unsigned int dbid);
    unsigned int getID(void);
    void setID(unsigned int myID);
protected:
    unsigned int id;
};

/* Curiously recurring template paradigm */
template<class Derived>
class PersonDBX: public virtual personDB
{
    using personDB::personDB;
protected:
    static const std::string tableName;
    static const personRelationTable personIDtable;
public:
    static std::string static_getTableName(){ return tableName; }
    std::string getTableName(){return tableName;}
    static std::string static_getIDTableName(){ return personIDtable.tableName; }
    std::string getIDTableName(){return personIDtable.tableName;}

    static std::string static_getCol1TableID(){ return personIDtable.col1; }
    std::string getCol1TableID(){return personIDtable.col1;}

    static std::string static_getCol2TableID(){ return personIDtable.col2; }
    std::string getCol2TableID(){return personIDtable.col2;}



    personDBX(QString dbName, QString dbSurname, unsigned int dbid):personDB(dbName, dbSurname)
    {
        id = dbid;
    }
    PersonDBX():personDB(){;}

    PersonDBX(QString dbName, QString dbSurname):personDB(dbName, dbSurname){;}
};
template<class Derived> const std::string PersonDBX<Derived>::tableName = "Null";
template<class Derived> const personRelationTable PersonDBX<Derived>::personIDtable = {"Null", "Null", "Null"};

#endif // PERSONDB_H
```

File persondb.cpp

```
#include "persondb.h"

personDB::personDB(QString dbName, QString dbSurname, unsigned int dbid):person(dbName, dbSurname){

    id = dbid;
}

personDB::personDB(std::string dbName, std::string dbSurname,
                   unsigned int dbid):person(dbName, dbSurname){

    id = dbid;
}

unsigned int personDB::getID(void){
    return id;
}

void personDB::setID(unsigned int myID)
{
    id = myID;
}
```

The child class is scriptby:

file scriptby.h

```
#ifndef SCRIPT_H
#define SCRIPT_H

#include "persondb.h"

class ScriptBy : public PersonDBX<ScriptBy>
{
public:
    using PersonDBX::PersonDBX;
    ScriptBy(QString dbName, QString dbSurname, unsigned int dbid);
protected:
};

#endif // SCRIPT_H
```

file scriptby.cpp

```
#include "scriptby.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <globals.h>

template<> const std::string PersonDBX<ScriptBy>::tableName = "ScriptBy";
template<> const personRelationTable PersonDBX<ScriptBy>::personIDtable = {"Story_ScriptBy","StoryID", "ScriptByID"};

ScriptBy::ScriptBy(QString dbName, QString dbSurname, unsigned int dbid):PersonDBX(dbName, dbSurname)
{
    id = dbid;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to make the inherited class member function static?

You can't. You can rename the `static` function to something else and use it from the regular member function, if that makes sense for your class.

```
class ScriptBy : public personDB
{
    virtual std::string getTableName() { return getTableNameStatic(); }
    static std::string getTableNameStatic();
};
```

Answer (score 1):

`virtual` and `static` represent 2 contradicting requirements.

`static` function is a **class-level** construct and isn't constrained to any specific class instance.

`virtual` function is an **instance-level** construct and as such it's behavior is defined by a relevant object.

You'll need to reconsider your requirements.

Answer (score -2):

*"Is there a way to make the inherited class member function static?"* No